If x is uniform, what is [∣>′] for ′∈[0,1]?
This is a very simple question but I am failing to check if my answer is correct:
Given that $x \sim U[0,1]$, what is the $E[x  |x > x']$ where $x'$ is within $[0,1]$?
My answer would be that its $(1-x'^2) /2$ but I am not sure it is correct.
What did I do ? I used the following formula: $ \int_{x'}^1 x f_x dx$ where $f_x =1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Please try to use more descriptive titles.  The fact that your title is "Conditional expectation of uniform random variable 2" suggests that you have discovered that there is already a question titled ""Conditional expectation of uniform random variable", and you have appended a "2" to the end to change the title enough that you can post the question.  This is not good practice.  Instead, write a title which gives some more detail about your question, e.g. "If $X$ is uniform, what is $E[x\mid x>x']$ for $x' \in [0,1]$?"

Why does your $X$ change to $x$ when it is in the expectation?

You're half-right. As a matter of fact, you're forgetting to restrain your probability space to the event of interest. To account for that, you should divide the expression you've provided by the probability of that conditional event, or, equivalently, by the expectation of the indicator function. That happens because of the law of the conditional expectation (the corollary of the Bayes' theorem):
$$
\mathbb{E} (X \mid A)=\sum _{x}xP(X=x \mid A) = \sum _{x}x{\frac {P(\{X=x\}\cap A)}{P(A)}}
$$
In statistic notation that would be:
$$
\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mathbf{U}_{[0;1]}}[x | x > x'] = 
\frac{\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mathbf{U}_{[0;1]}}[x \mathbf {1}_{[x>x']}]}{\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mathbf{U}_{[0;1]}}[\mathbf {1}_{[x>x']}]} = 
\frac{\int_{0}^{1}x \mathbf {1}_{[x>x']}\,dx}{\int_{0}^{1} \mathbf {1}_{[x>x']}\,dx} = 
\frac{\int_{x'}^{1}x\,dx}{\int_{x'}^{1}\,dx} = 
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-x'^2}{1-x'} = \frac{1}{2}(1+x')
$$
Note, how that makes a lot of sense when you start plugging in values of $x'$:

for $x'=0$ it yields $\mathbb{E}[x | x > x'] =\frac{1}{2}$ and that is totally true for $x$ is uniform at unit interval.
for $x'=1$ it yields $\mathbb{E}[x | x > x'] = 1$ and that is totally true for $x$ can take values none other than one.


This is an amazing answer, thank you so much for your help!!!
